# How to restrict svn commands in svnserve

Tags: linux, svn, svnserve, svn-ssh

I am using svn+ssh to interact with repositories. I would like to know if there is any mechanism to retrict users to only a set of svn commands, for example, to prevent the use of locks.

In the worst case scenario, if I have to modify the source code, any pointers to which file needs to be modified would also help. I see that there is svnserve.c file but a quick review tells me that that may not be the right file to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the use of locks with [pre-lock](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/pre-lock/) and [pre-unlock](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/pre-unlock/) hook scripts. Make the hook exit with any code besides `0` and users won't be able to lock or unlock files. E.g., add a hook with just one line

```
exit 1
```

Comment: Just checked, before accepting your answer, that hooks are available for commands other than lock. They are.